# How do I install ubuntu on my computer and not a USB stick?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I'm running ubuntu off my USB drive, and the "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" wizard keeps trying to install ubuntu on my USB drive rather than my real computer, and I can't seem to change it.

How do I resolve this problem?